# Is there a predefined upload limit to $_FILES in PHP?

Tags: php, file, upload

Hi I'm fairly new to HTML, PHP, MySQL etc.. I am wondering if there is a predefined upload limit using `$_FILES`. I ask because when I try to upload 8 images of around 1.5 megabytes the code does not work but when I upload 10 images of around 60 kilobytes the code works fine.
Here is my code and feel free to make any criticisms/comments about it:

```
</head>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="file" name="image[]" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>    

<?php

include 'connect.php';

if(!empty($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])){

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'jpeg');
    $count = 0;
    foreach($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $name){

    $image_name = $name;
    $tmp = explode('.', $image_name);

    $image_extn = strtolower(end($tmp)); //can only reference file
    $image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$count];
    $count = $count +1;

    if(in_array($image_extn, $allowed) === true){

        $image_path = 'images/' . md5($image_name) . '.' . $image_extn;

        move_uploaded_file($image_temp, $image_path);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO store VALUES ('', '$image_name', '$image_path')") or die(mysql_error());

        $lastid = mysql_insert_id();
        $image_link = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id = $lastid");
        $image_link = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_link);
        $image_link = $image_link['image'];
        $uploaded[] = $image_link;

        }
        else{
            echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
            echo implode(', ', $allowed);
            }
        }
    }        

    if(!empty($uploaded)){
        foreach($uploaded as  $new){
            echo "<a href = $new>$new</a><p></p>";

        }
    }
else{
        echo "Please select an image.";
    }
?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to upload an array of files, you will not be able to upload more than 20 files due to [max_file_uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) limit in `php.ini` which is by default set to `20`.

So you have to increase this limit to upload more than 20 files.

**Note**: `max_file_uploads` can NOT be changed outside php.ini. See [PHP "Bug" #50684](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50684&edit=1)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the settings you want to change in php.ini:

**post_max_size**
This setting controls the size of an HTTP post, and it needs to be set larger than the upload_max_filesize setting.

**upload_max_filesize**
This value sets the maximum size of an upload file.

Remember to restart your web server after making these changes.

Ref:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

Answer (score 0):

A few settings in your php.ini could be causing this. Look into memory_limit, post_max_size, upload_max_filesize. You could also be timing out. The best way to find out specifically is `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors','1');`

Answer (score 0):

In php.ini, there will be a `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` directive.

You should also define a `MAX_FILE_SIZE` hidden input within your form, as per
http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php